# MVC C#, Partial View, Jquery load() not working properly after .load() is called

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using C#, MVC.

I am having a problem with PartialView and jquery load working properly.

When the user clicks on a hyperlink called Kit, I call the following:

```
    public ActionResult KitsEdit(string id)
    {
        int idnbr = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        var Progs = db2.usp_KitInfo(idnbr)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.TDate).ToList();


        return PartialView(Progs);
    }
```

which loads a PartialView on the page fine.

the View has rows and for each row has an edit hyperlink. 
When the user clicks on the Edit hyperlink, I show a dialog box where the user can modify that some of the info on that appears on each row and hit submit. This works fine the first time.

On submit, I call I do some validation and then call:

```
    $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("KitsEdit", "Spr")' + '?id=' + '@Model.id');
```

as I need to reload the partial view on the page so the user can see the updated information.

The load of the page works fine on the surface. What happens though is that when I click on Edit hyperlink a SECOND time after I did the .load and the dialogbox shows up some of the functionality that worked before simply doesn't work. For example, the checkbox doesn't work in that if I click it, the value doesn't get passes properly back to the controller action. Also, for the submit, I had some code on click but those don't even  work. It goes diectly to the controller action and bypasses all of the code in

```
    $("#submit").click(function ().
```

Note that this happens only after the load() is called.

Question: Is there anything besides the .load() that will load a PartialView on the page. If not, how can I get it to work properly with the .load().

Below is what the submit click looks like:

```
    $("#submit").click(function () {
    //  following .on code won't execute code inside of function so have it commented       
    // $("#submit").on("click", function () {  

         var inactivedate = $("#InactiveDate").val();

         var inactivecheck = $('#Inactive').is(':checked');

         var inactivereason = $('#InactiveReason option:selected').text();

         if ((!inactivedate || !$.trim(inactivedate)) && $('#Inactive_cb').attr('checked') == true) {
             alert('Inactive Date must be entered.');
             return false;
         }

         if ($('#Inactive_cb').attr('checked') == true && inactivereason == '<Choose>') {
             alert('Inactive Reason must be selected.');
             return false;
         }

         var url = '@Url.Action("EditTrain", "Spr")';


         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             async: false,
             data: $('#theForm').serialize()               
           });


         $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("kitsEdit", "Spr")' + '?id=' + '@Model.spkrid');
         parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();

         return false;

     });
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` function is injecting some new contents to the DOM dynamically . So the old event bindings wont work for the new elements. You need to use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Change

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
  //some code 
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click","#submit",function (e) {
  e.preventDefault() // if you need
  //some code 
});
```

[jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) works for current and future elements.

Comment: Shyju - Thank you for your response. I replaced  $("#submit").click(function () {  with $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () { but seems like nothing within $(document).on("click","#submit",function () {  seems get executed. The code goes directly to the Controller Action bypassing the click code.

Comment: @NatePet : IF you want to prevent the default submit behaviour, use preventDefault method. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it with e.preventDefault() but still not luck. The code inside of $(document).on("click","#submit",function (e) isn't being executed

Comment: check for other script errors and make sure you have all these code in the document ready event

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any of the JavaScript code in the partial View?  If you have any events wired up in the partial View, they won't work when you reload the control.

If you need to rebind the events, do it in the `success` function after your AJAX call is made.

Comment: Thanks Garrett, but no program gets called in $("#submit").click(function () after the .load(). As such, even teh success doesn't work. I tried that after you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're using .load() correctly, but you need to change the event handler to bind the event on newly created elements using .on() or .delegate().  like this:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
  //do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have fixed the issue with the check box working. But when I click on submit, it doesn't execute any of the code though. Any idea?

Comment: any way you could fiddle your problem? I'm having trouble understanding. At least show the code in $("#submit").click()

Comment: Hi Juventus18 - I have uploaded the submit code. I can't quite fiddle it as I have controller that that goes to. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't use .on() for the #submit click handler. Please try that first and update your code.

Comment: Juventus18 - If I try it with .on, it doesn't execute any code within. I tried it. I will update it though

Comment: what mode of colorbox are you using (AJAX? IFrame?...) Also, I think a fiddle might still be a good thing to do here. You can simulate your AJAX calls (see in sidebar, "Testing AJAX requests") I haven't used the feature, but I'd imagine you just make the call to the appropriate page and on the success handler, just return a string (your rendered partial). I know that seems like a lot of work to put this into fiddle, and by no means am I saying you HAVE to to figure this out. Use your own judgement how much time you want to put into it and how important this feature is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").live('click', function () {}
```

This should work

Comment: live is now depreciated.